# phpmyadmin or other mysql gui - edit whole table from one screen

Tags: linux, mysql, phpmyadmin

Let's say I have table in database. I'd like to be able to view all data from this table and be able to edit every field from single screen. I tried to do this in phpmyadmin but I'm not sure how... I can see all data but I have to click edit on single field and then I'm sent to next screen, can't really edit everything at once.

How do I do this in phpmyadmin or other mysql gui? I'm on Linux, my server too.

---

I'd like each field in table to be editable text field - maybe this will show better what I'm searching for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it have to be web based? If not, you could always use the [MySQL GUI Tools](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html) as provided by MySQL. There are downloads for Windows, Mac and Linux platforms.

The one you'll want to use is MySQL Query Browser. The other tools, like MySQL Administrator, are useful for backing up and creating table relationships visually.

[image: query browser view]

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be web based. Will this one let me edit like this? How do I do it, any tutorials?

Comment: Um... have you ever used a spreadsheet program, like Excel? It's very similar to that. Very, very easy to learn. You can edit multiple fields and then apply the update all at once.

Comment: Like spreadsheet? Ah, so I can just click and it will edit? It might be it, I'll try it.

Comment: @lorem I've included a screenshot and a little more information. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [emma](http://freshmeat.net/projects/emma/) is worth a try. I found it quite useful and easy to use.

Comment: Yeah I'd like to edit all these fields at the same time not click on each one and get pop-up window xP (as I assume emma works after looking at screenshots)

Comment: If you mean [this](http://freshmeat.net/screenshots/b5/9e/b59eaa25092c7d4ea2f7278d1a5f5295_medium.png?1237058207) screenshot, well that's the editing of the *structure* of a table and not its content. As far as I remember it's possible to edit the fields just like a spreadsheet. Take a try if you want.